# Remove force when objects collide in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision

I m getting one issue in my game. I am Colliding two objects one of bullet type and another is of dynamic type. When my bullet type object collide with dynamic type object then it add force to other object(don't know whether it is force or not) due which other objects are getting disturb.

I check below line in postcollision

```
print( "Collision force: " .. event.force)
```

but I'm getting a `nil` value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set up your post collision function. Here is an example that works for me.

```
local function collisionFunction( self, event )
     print( "Collision force: " .. event.force)
end

object.postCollision = collisionFunction
object:addEventListener('postCollision', object)
```

This should print out the force of the collision between the 2 objects.